# trying to attach object property to image onclick for a jquery game

Tags: jquery, onclick, javascript-objects

preface: I wrote my first line of code 3-20-17

Okay, so I'm in the proccess of building a RPG game, where the user has an option of four characters to be their fighter - once they choose a fighter, the other three are now the enemy, the fighter having to defeat all to win.  I have an object set up housing all character properties - attack,  counter, and health - needed for the game to run once the player has chosen a fighter.
I have an image representing the character, need that image to = the appropriate object property (characters.name)

ive also tried making images button.

```html
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h4 class="text-center" id="header">Star Wars RPG</h4>
        <h6 class="text-center text-muted" id="instructions">Select a Fighter to take on the force of ooposition. You must defeat all three remaining characters - so choose wisely! May the force be with you!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             
             <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left">
                 <div class="panel panel-primary">
                     <div class="panel-heading text-center preFightPanel">
           <h3 id="preFightPanel"></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="leftovers">
          <p class="preGameArena"></p>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="assets/images/imageObi.jpg" class="charChoices" id="imageObi" value="unsure">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="assets/images/imageDarth.png" class="charChoices" id="imageDarth" value="dark">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="assets/images/imageYoda.png" class="charChoices" id="imageYoda" value="jedi">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="assets/images/imageYtwoDtwo.png" class="charChoices" id="imageYtwoDtwo" value="machine">
           </div>
           </div>
          
        </div></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
      <div class="panel panel-primary" id="arena">
          <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
   <h3 class="text-center">Arena</h3>
   <div class="panel-body">
   <div><p id="fighter"></p></div>
   <h4 id="enemy">
   
   <h4 id="battleStats"></h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div></div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="attackButton">
              <h4>Attack</h4>
           </button>
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

here is my js code

```js
Array.prototype.inArrayStarwars = function inArrayStarwars(value){
 for (i=0; i < this.length; i++){
  if(this [i === value]){
   return true;
  }
 }
return false;
}
$(document).ready(function(){    
     alert("hey0");   
var yodaAudio;
var yTwoAudio;
var saberAudio;
var darthAudio;
var obiAudio;

///// characters \\\\
var characters = {



 "obi" : {
  name: "obi",
  health: 300,
  attack: 8,
  counter: 40,
  imagePath: "assets/images/imageObi.jpg"
 },

 
 "yoda" : {
  name: "yoda",
  health: 360,
  attack: 7,
  counter: 40,
  imagePath: "assets/images/imageDarth.png"

 },


 "ytwoDtwo": {
  name: "ytwoDtwo",
  health: 240,
  attack: 8,
  counter: 30,
  imagePath: "assets/images/imageYtwoDtwo.png"
 },


 "vader" : {
  name: "vader",
  health: 200,
  attack: 14,
  counter: 10,
 
  }
 

};







$("#preFightPanel").html("Characters");

var round = 1;
var battlesWon = [];
var enemyLockerRoom = [];
var preWarlockerRoom = [];
var battleVictory;
var warWon = false;
var fighterPicked = false;
var currentFighter = "";
var jedi = characters.yoda;
var dark = characters.vader;
var unsure = characters.obi;
var machine = characters.ytwoDtwo;



var attack = $("#attackButton").on("click", function(){
 for(i = 0; i < characters.obi.attack; i++){
  --(characters.ytwoDtwo.health);
  alert(characters.ytwoDtwo.health);
 }

})


// was attempting to push image into array upon click, then check if value is one of four values - "dark", "unsure", "jedi", "machine" - already attached to character images. if so, then have that corresponding image = the correct character.name \\\\
// this will be the function that renders all characters\\
var letsGo = $(".charChoices").on("click", function(makeChar){
 preWarlockerRoom.push(this);
 preWarlockerRoom.inArrayStarwars("dark");


 

 

 
        $("#fighter").append(this);
        alert("Nice Selection! Now you must carefully choose your first opponent. Remember - you're going to have to defeat everyone to win the game.");
     
 

        $(leftovers.children).animate({right: '900px'});
        $(leftovers.children).removeClass("charChoices").addClass("currentEnemy");
        $(leftovers.children).animate({left: '-10px'});
        $("#preFightPanel").html("Enemies");
      


    });
   
  });
```

not sure if I have the right idea - if someone where to nusge me in the right direction, i would bevery greatful. Thanks in advance

Robert

Comment: `if(this [i === value]){` should be `if(this [i] === value){`

Comment: But if you're using jQuery, why don't you just use `$.inArray` instead of writing your own function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe because I was so unsure of what was going on, being so new to coding, I may have muddled the actual issue.  I have a game, an RPG, and need the visual representation of characters (the images) to represent the associated character property in the object I created to house the game's characters.  I removed the hard-copy images. using the `.append()` to append all object values to screen. Here's how:

HTML:

```html
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h4 class="text-center" id="header">Star Wars RPG</h4>
        <h6 class="text-center text-muted" id="instructions">Select a Fighter to take on the force of ooposition. You must defeat all three remaining characters - so choose wisely! May the force be with you!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             
             <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left preGamejitter">
                 <div class="panel panel-primary">
                     <div class="panel-heading text-center preFightPanel">
           <h3 id="preFightPanel"></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="leftovers">
          <p class="preGameArena"></p>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- <img src="assets/images/imageObi.jpg" class="charChoices" id="imageObi" value="unsure"> -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- <img src="assets/images/imageDarth.png" class="charChoices" id="imageDarth" value="dark"> -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- <img src="assets/images/imageYoda.png" class="charChoices" id="imageYoda" value="jedi"> -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- <img src="assets/images/imageYtwoDtwo.png" class="charChoices" id="imageYtwoDtwo" value="machine"> -->
           </div>
           </div>
          
        </div></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
      <div class="panel panel-primary" id="arena">
          <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
   <h3 class="text-center" id="arenal">Arena</h3>
   <div class="panel-body">
   <div><p id="fighter"></p></div>
   <h4 id="enemy">
   
   <h4 id="battleStats"></h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div></div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="attackButton">
              <h4>Attack</h4>
           </button>
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

and here is the actual code that renders character on screen, image being the actual values of appropriate character in characters object.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
 $("#arena").hide();
 $("#attackButton").hide();


   

 
 
 
    

     
var yodaAudio;
var yTwoAudio;
var saberAudio;
var darthAudio;
var obiAudio;

///// characters \\\\
var characters = {



 "obi" : {
  name: "obi",
  health: 300,
  attack: 8,
  counter: 40,
  imagePath: "assets/images/imageObi.jpg"
 },

 
 "yoda" : {
  name: "yoda",
  health: 360,
  attack: 7,
  counter: 40,
  imagePath: "assets/images/imageYoda.png"

 },


 "ytwoDtwo": {
  name: "ytwoDtwo",
  health: 240,
  attack: 8,
  counter: 30,
  imagePath: "assets/images/imageYtwoDtwo.png"
 },


 "vader" : {
  name: "vader",
  health: 200,
  attack: 14,
  counter: 10,
  imagePath:  "assets/images/imageDarth.png"
 
  }
 

};

  var yTwoDtwoDiv = $("<div class='charChoicesDIV' data-name='" + characters.ytwoDtwo + "'>");
    var yTwoDtwoName = $("<div class='character-name'>").text("YtwoDtwo");
    var yTwoDtwoImage = $("<img alt='image' class='character-image'>").attr("src", characters.ytwoDtwo.imagePath);
    var yTwoDtwoHealth = $("<div class='character-health'>").text(characters.ytwoDtwo.health);

var yodaDiv = $("<div class='charChoicesDIV' data-name='" + characters.yoda + "'>");
    var yodaName = $("<div class='character-name'>").text("Yoda");
    var yodaImage = $("<img alt='image' class='character-image'>").attr("src", characters.yoda.imagePath);
    var yodaHealth = $("<div class='character-health'>").text(characters.yoda.health);
      
 

    

 var obiDiv = $("<div class='charChoicesDIV' data-name='" + characters.obi + "'>");
    var obiName = $("<div class='character-name'>").text("Obi");
    var obiImage = $("<img alt='image' class='character-image'>").attr("src", characters.obi.imagePath);
    var obiHealth = $("<div class='character-health'>").text(characters.obi.health);
   


     var darthDiv = $("<div class='charChoicesDIV' data-name='" + characters.vader + "'>");
    var darthName = $("<div class='character-name'>").text("Darth Vader");
    var darthImage = $("<img alt='image' class='character-image'>").attr("src", characters.vader.imagePath);
    var darthHealth = $("<div class='character-health'>").text(characters.vader.health);





$("#preFightPanel").html("Characters");

yodaDiv.append(yodaName).append(yodaImage).append(yodaHealth);
$("#leftovers").append(yodaDiv);
yTwoDtwoDiv.append(yTwoDtwoName).append(yTwoDtwoImage).append(yTwoDtwoHealth);
 $("#leftovers").append(yTwoDtwoDiv);
 obiDiv.append(obiName).append(obiImage).append(obiHealth);
 $("#leftovers").append(obiDiv);
 darthDiv.append(darthName).append(darthImage).append(darthHealth);
 $("#leftovers").append(darthDiv);
});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh, If I understood correctly you could:

```
var character = {...};
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('img.myImage').data("character_data", JSON.stringify(character));
});
```

And then you could retrieve it by:

```
var character = JSON.parse($('img.myImage').data("character_data"));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, let me remind that there's a JS library for HTML5 game dev called [p5js](https://p5js.org/) which is super handy to use, it also comes with an explicit plugin for game dev [p5play](http://p5play.molleindustria.org/)

Comment: thanks, man. I'm currently in a boot camp, was working on my homework on my lunch break. will fully investigate this a little later - thanks!

Comment: I used to bootcamp for Counter-strike trainings hehehe

Comment: So I was attempting to make a comparison post click, see if image value matched one of the four characters , and if so, have image = character.whatevername. Then my actual gameplay function would be fairly simple, housed in the attack button. I wonder, this solution of yours, do you think it'd be better in the .ready function? Again, haven't even had a chance to play with it - just thinking...

Comment: so I ended up fixing the issue - check out the answer I posted!  Sorry that I was so unclear on what my question actually was lol.